Reducing the width of data validation list - Excel
I can't seem to find an easy, VBA free way of reducing the width of the validation list below to fit the data. The source list alos has a narrow column width. So too does the destination data. Any ideas would be really appreciated.
Data Validation List Too Wide


I don't think that this is possible.

The width of the data validation is not determined by its source. Don't think you can do it.
